# How to call a function in a function in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to wrap functions with a function for protection purpose.

My Code:

```
function Lib()
  function self:foo(x, y) return x+y end
  function self:goo(x, y) return x-y end
end
print(Lib():foo(3, 2))
```

I expect to get `5` but I get the following error.

`attempt to index a nil value (global 'self')`

What is wrong with my code and how to fix this?

ADDED: Can anyone compare this with using `Lib = {}` instead? I'm considering to wrap functions with a function since writing `self:` is easier to maintain than writing `Lib.` which can be changed later. I wonder if my idea makes sense.

---

EDITED: Okay, I just found out this works.

```
function Lib()
  function foo(x, y) return x+y end
  function goo(x, y) return x-y end
  return self
end
Lib()
print(foo(3, 2))
```

But I don't understand why. Can't functions inside a function be protected?

P.S: I'm sorry if my question is stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are values that are created when function definitions are executed. Any variable can reference a function value.

So, although a function definition might inside another function body, the function value it not inside the function. It is available via whatever expressions, table keys and fields, and variables that reference it.

Variables are global or local (including parameters). If a name of a variable is not previously declared as local, it is global. So, executing this code:

```
function Lib()
  function foo(x, y) return x+y end
  function goo(x, y) return x-y end
  return self
end
```

Sets the global variable `Lib` to the function value created by evaluating the function definition. That's all up to that point.

Then, executing:

```
Lib()
```

Uses the value of the global variable `Lib`, assumes it's a function and calls it with no parameters. That executes the function, which evaluates a function definition to obtain a function value and sets it to the global variable `foo`; similarly for `goo`; and returns the value of the global variable `self` (presumably `nil`). The return value is discarded because the call doesn't do anything with it.

Then, executing:

```
print(foo(3, 2))
```

Uses the value of the global variable `foo`, assumes it's a function and calls it with two parameters. That executes the function, which returns 5. It then uses the value of the global variable `print`, assumes it's a function and calls it with the value 5. The return value is discarded because the call doesn't do anything with it.

Other answers are leading you to what you might want to do. You can evaluate what they are suggesting using these principles.

Answer (score 3):

```
function Lib()
   local function foo(x, y) return x+y end
   local function goo(x, y) return x-y end

   interface = {}
   interface.foo = foo
   interface.goo = goo

   return interface
end
```

So:

```
l = Lib()
print(l.foo(3, 2))
```

will print `5`

Is that what you need? There is no direct access to the `foo` and `goo` functions.

The next idea this leads to is to *not* expose, say, the `goo` function via `interface`, but just use it within `foo` or some other function. In that case, `goo` would be an implementation detail (a private function), not exposed via the object interface.

Answer (score 3):

An implicit `self` parameter only exists in the body of `:` method functions.

Since `Lib` isn't defined with a `:`, there is no `self` variable.

You can instead make a factory/constructor which makes a blank instance and attaches the methods:

```
function new(factor)
    local instance = {factor = factor}

    function instance:multiply(n)
        return self.factor * n
    end

    return instance
end

local m = new(5)
print(m:multiply(6)) --> 3
```

If you really want a *class* of which you have many instances, instead of defining a function for each instance, you would attach a metatable to "automatically" attach all of the properties:

```
local Class = {}

function Class.new(factor)
    local instance = {factor = factor}

    return setmetatable(instance, {__index = Class})
end

function Class:multiply(n)
    return self.factor * n
end

local m = Class.new(5)
print(m:multiply(6)) --> 30
```